# React not able to dynamically render correct component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {loggedIn: true}
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Helmet>
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
                </Helmet>
                <Wrapper state={this.state.loggedIn}/>
            </div>

        )

    }
}
```

This passes the loggedIn state down to a wrapper component. This wrapper dynamically determines which component to render. Here's the wrapper code,

```
class Wrapper extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const MainComp = this.props.state.loggedIn ? Logged : Unlogged;
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div className="wrapper">
                    <Header state={this.props.state}/>
                    <MainComp state={this.props.state}/>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

The issue is even when the loggedIn variable is false the correct component is rendered. However when I change it to true it still continues to render the old or incorrect component.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How are you changing it?

Comment: @EddieDelRio by manually changing the value of the loggedIn variable from true to false.

Comment: That won't work. You're gonna have to rerender the state by using `this.setState`

Comment: Can you include sample code on how you're manually changing it?

Comment: @EddieDelRio I'm new to React, can you help me with how to do it?

Comment: As i mentioned right now I'm just replacing true with false manually.

Comment: Also pass down state not state.loggedin.

Comment: You passed down the wrong prop. Take a gander at the revisions I made and it should resolve the problem. Currently `this.props.state.loggedIn` is `undefined` which always evaluates to `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `state={this.state.loggedIn}` which will be true or false
but in your child you get `this.props.state.loggedIn` which is not defined at all because `state === loggedIn`

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {loggedIn: true}
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Helmet>
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
                </Helmet>
                <Wrapper state={this.state}/>
            </div>

        )

    }
}
```

Call the constructor with props on your child class.

```js
class Wrapper extends React.Component 
{
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
  }

    render() {
        const MainComp = this.props.state.loggedIn ? Logged : Unlogged;
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div className="wrapper">
                    <Header state={this.props.state}/>
                    <MainComp state={this.props.state}/>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: So this works and the correct component is rendered, but I'm also getting ```Line 9:  Useless constructor  no-useless-constructor```

Comment: Odd. What are you using to compile?

Comment: Try deleting the wrapper constructor. I don't see why that'd give an error. Also, mark as answered to close the question if your problem is resolved